# Manipulating data in a DataGridView VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

It's pretty simple really but I can't seem to find anything that relates to this without using a database.

Basically I want to simply take data out of a row of cells in the dataGridView that will of been inputted by the user and then manipulate that data as I like. This is without using a database, simply by temporarily storing the values in VB.

Such as in Excel you can perform a calculation between two cells next to each other and apply this calculation to every other cell. I imagine you can do this by using a counter however I am unsure of the basics first.

Comment: Can you add more information about the workflow? Are you working with integers? You can store the values in an array or variables and then write methods to accomplish your logic

Comment: You haven't really explained yourself very well because what you say in your second paragraph is then basically contradicted by what you say in your third paragraph.  Getting data from a row and manipulating it is easy: simply index the `Rows` collection to get a row, index its `Cells` collection to get a cell and then get and/or set its `Value` property.  Applying a formula to multiple rows by dragging is something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry I wrote this in the middle of the night, was so tired I couldn't concentrate. What I want to do is select a cell in two different columns. The column names are force and area. I want to select the first two cells in these columns and divide them.I'll be storing the values in an array.  I'll be then applying this to a graph.

Comment: The cell will contain an integer and I want to extract that integer and store this separately so I can apply the maths. The problem I seem to be encountering is that I can't store the values as integer. "ss = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0)" ss is the integer I am trying to store the cell in however I get the error message saying "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' cannot be converted to integer".